# Integrating a Raphael library within SVG-edit. Compatibility issues?

Tags: javascript, html, raphael, graphael, svg-edit

Is it possible to use a Raphael library such as this one : https://github.com/poilu/raphael-boolean within SVG-edit, that uses plain SVG? :

SVG-edit website:https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/

I have tried to marry them both but i am guessing they dont return the same pathstrings so that i can use the raphael library in a clean way. Are they compatible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question now that i've done my research. Apparently yes, the pathstring format of both the native SVG and Raphael SVG specification are identical